# Linux chmod() results in errno 13

Tags: c, linux, chmod, errno

I am trying to set the mod of a new file to match the old one.  My Qt5/C++ codes is roughly:

```
stat(oldFileName.toLatin1().data(), &sb);
bool success = chmod(newFileName.toLatin1().data(),sb.st_mode)
```

The sb.st_mode value at the time of chmod being called is 33261 (octal 100755).  The chmod() call fails and sets errno to 13 (permission denied).  yet the program is running as uid 0 gid 0.

---

UPDATE: Looks like stat() also includes file TYPE information in the higher bits I need to remove.  I tried to use (sb.st_mode & 0x1FF which yields 0755) as the value for chmod but still fails.

Comment: Dumb question: Are you sure newFileName is valid and exists etc ?

Comment: You have to have write permission on the folder containing the file whose permission you want to change

Comment: Since running as uid 0 (root) yes it has permission, and yes the file exists.  There's some clue in https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html I'm just reading

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/luikxm/how_to_understand_the_permission_33261_from_stat/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly chmod() and chown() return 0 for success, -1 for failure.  Which is the opposite of C/C++ standard (0 for false, non-0 for true).

So you have to reverse the function return value to use as a boolean.

Comment: GNU [checking for errors](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Checking-for-Errors.html) says that "Most library functions return a special value to indicate that they have failed. The special value is typically -1, a null pointer, or a constant such as EOF". But, yes, the OP's success variable appears to be inverted.

Comment: @Haris Been there, done that. ;-)

Comment: True and false have nothing to do with success and failure. Most functions return 0 for success which means you have every other integer to use as an error code. There is one success and many ways to fail.